# jenkins.war got deleted while server update

Tags: jenkins

Our Jenkins server is an AWS EC-2 ubuntu instance. After we ran the server patching we are unable to find the jenkins.war file in the server.
Code for server patching used:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y dist-upgrade
sudo reboot
```

Getting this error while trying to start jenkins:

```
Error: Unable to access jarfile /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war
```

Is it possible the server upgrade might have deleted the jenkins.war file?

Is there a way to retrieve the old jenkins jobs and run the server again?

Comment: Are you positive you were not using instance storage for Jenkins and that the instance was just rebooted and not stopped?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is relevant for you since we are not on the same OS, but my `jenkins.war` lives in `/usr/lib/jenkins/`.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible that the jenkins.war file got deleted during the automated upgrade process. Since I had java 1.7 installed on the server the automated upgrade process must have failed as the recent versions of jenkins require java 1.8. Upgrading java version to java 1.8 and running apt-get install jenkins resolved the issue.